# How can I force javascript event manually while importing the xlsx file in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, dom-events, xlsx, import-from-excel

I am using below code snippet to import the xlsx file in Javascript. This code is working fine and I'm able to import the xlsx. As added change `addEventListener`, whenever I choose (select) file event is triggering and importing the file.

```
 <input type="file" name="xlfile" id="xlf" /> 
 <br />
 <input type="button" id="import" value="Import" />
 //some other javascript code


  var xlf = document.getElementById('xlf');
  function handleFile(e) {
  var files = e.target.files;
  var f = files[0];
   {
     var reader = new FileReader();
     var name = f.name;
     reader.onload = function(e) {
     var data = e.target.result;
     var wb;
     wb = X.read(data, {type: 'binary'});
     process_wb(wb);
    };
    if(rABS) reader.readAsBinaryString(f);
    else reader.readAsArrayBuffer(f);
}
}

if(xlf.addEventListener) xlf.addEventListener('change', handleFile, false);
```

But I want import the file whenever I click on import button. For that I replaced the above line with:

```
var import= document.getElementById('import');
if(import.addEventListener) import.addEventListener('click', handleFile, false);
```

In this case, I'm unable to get the input file inside `handleFile(e)` method.

Comment: _"But I want import the file whenever I click on import button."_ What do you mean by "import the file"? Are you trying to request a file from user filesystem at click of `input type="button"` element?

Comment: @guest271314  Yes, I'm trying to get the file at click of import button, I got the anwser from jakub, thank you

Answer (score 0):

The variable name 'import' is a reserved word. Try changing the variable name.

Answer (score 0):

You can access the selected file from xlf variable.

```
var xlf = document.getElementById('xlf');
function handleFile(e) {
  var files = xlf.files;
  var f = files[0];
  var reader = new FileReader();
  var name = f.name;
  reader.onload = function(e) {
    var data = e.target.result;
    var wb;
    wb = X.read(data, {type: 'binary'});
    process_wb(wb);
  };
  if(rABS) 
    reader.readAsBinaryString(f);
  else 
    reader.readAsArrayBuffer(f);
}
```

Also change the name for "import" variable. Import is a reserved word, it's used for loading modules (new feature added in ES2015).

```
var importButton = document.getElementById('import');
if (importButton.addEventListener) 
  importButton.addEventListener('click', handleFile, false);
```

Comment: This is the line which I require var files = xlf.files;  Thanks a lot Jakub, it is working perfectly.